# Mathematics based only on real numbers

Tags: soft-question, big-picture

I'm aware that >90% will outright reject this, so feel free to ignore it. I'd much appreciate those trying to figure out in which way this question (or rather its eventual answer) would make sense.

**Is there a way to construct the foundations of mathematics from just the real numbers?
If not, why not?**

Background: The real world (space, time) is arguably best described as a continuum. So it would make sense to take that as a foundation. Integers would only occur later e.g. as winding numbers, not as fundamental. All discrete things would be secondary. A continuous version of sets would probably be part of the foundation.

Rant: This construction from set theory to integers to rational numbers only to find that real numbers are then kind of problematic in the framework. I just can't see any sense in that.

Comment: If you want an axiomatization of *just the real numbers* then Book 5 of [Euclid](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_Elements#Contents) (or similar) might do. If you want $\mathbf R$-based “foundation for all mathematics” your problem would be to translate from the language (sets) most of them are already written in.

Comment: I'm asking for the whole enchilada.

Comment: So how do you define, say, a function... Do you want to *eliminate sets*?

Comment: *"real numbers are then kind of problematic in the framework"* What do you mean?

Comment: (I was prepared to give away all of my 101 points away for downvotes, but then they tricked my by upvoting +3 first.) @user76284 I just don't like how real numbers are 'derived' starting from set theory. I was under the impression that they must be introduced this way. Or should be according to many. Maybe that's the misunderstanding.

Comment: @DoctorNuu The usual way real numbers are constructed from the rational numbers is through [Dedekind cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut) or [Cauchy sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence).

Comment: Exactly that is part of my criticism. This construction makes no sense. Nature does not care and has been continuous for a long time without Dedekind and Cauchy.

Comment: @DoctorNuu Why does it “not make sense”? Why don’t you apply the same objection to the construction of rational numbers, integers, and natural numbers?

Comment: @DoctorNuu Up to isomorphism, there is a *unique* Dedekind-complete ordered field, and this is what we mean when we talk about the real numbers. Dedekind cuts and Cauchy sequences show that one can *construct* (or “implement”) such a field starting from the rationals.

Answer (score 12):

$\mathbb{Z}$ is [not](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/263296/76284) first-order definable in $\mathbb{R}$ (as an ordered field) or $\mathbb{R}^n$ (as a vector space). That is, they cannot even "talk about" the integers.

As proven by Tarski, the theory of real closed fields is [decidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_of_first-order_theories_of_the_real_numbers). But even the weak theory of arithmetic [Q](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic) is essentially undecidable (any consistent extension of it is undecidable).

Comment: 1. Obviously we don't stop at $\mathbb{R}$ but also consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ Also no reason for integers to be "in" $\mathbb{R}$
2. This is a soft question, so maybe explain what decidability is good for.

Comment: @DoctorNuu $\mathbb{R}^n$, as a plain vector space, has an even weaker structure. “Also no reason for integers to be "in" ℝ.” It’s not about them being *in* $\mathbb{R}$, but about being able to define them (talk about them) *from* $\mathbb{R}$. And decidability is a sign that the theory is too weak, since even Robinson arithmetic is undecidable.

Comment: @DoctorNuu Put another way: the fact that the field of real numbers is decidable means that there is no way of "interpreting" (actually a technical term, but for now take it somewhat vaguely) the ring of integers in it. Going to $\mathbb{R}^n$ (even treated as an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra, which gives much more structure than as a mere vector space) doesn't help with this either; indeed, that's still interpretable in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The integers would be definable if, in addition to the field structure on the reals, we admitted the sine function. But I don't see how to define the sine without presupposing the integers.

Comment: Although the OP doesn't seem to like sets, continuous functions $R\to R^2$ seem to be OK since their winding numbers are mentioned. So it's unclear how much of second-order logic might be allowed. It doesn't take much to produce the integers that way. Of course, continuous functions can be coded as reals, but the coding doesn't seem to be the sort of thing the OP would approve.

Comment: Oh, this talk about OP. It's not about me, guys. It's about which concepts are based on which.

Comment: As this answer is so popular, maybe you could put it in a form where a non-'expert' can understand. First part would probably be sufficient. You are saying that one cannot talk about integers if one only has real numbers. Agreed. But my question is exactly that. What needs to be added in order find integers. E.g. as properties of functions.

Comment: @DoctorNuu Good question. I think the following works: Add a new predicate $\varphi$ to the language and the following axioms: $\varphi(0), \varphi(x+1) \leftrightarrow \varphi(x), 0 < x < 1 \rightarrow \neg \varphi(x)$. Or add a function $f$ and the axioms $0 \leq x < 1 \rightarrow f(x) = x$ and $f(x + 1) = f(x)$, i.e. the modulo 1 function. Then $\varphi(x) \leftrightarrow f(x) = 0$. Or add a function $g$ and the axioms $0 \leq x < 1 \rightarrow g(x) = 0$ and $g(x + 1) = g(x) + 1$, i.e. the floor function. Then $\varphi(x) \leftrightarrow g(x) = x$.

Comment: @DoctorNuu See also Pete L. Clark's [*Real Induction*](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/realinduction.pdf) (related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319153/version-of-the-axiom-of-induction-for-real-induction)).